# PHPUnit - Mocking a database function

Tags: php, pdo, tdd, phpunit

Here's a highly simplified version of the class I'm trying to test:

```
class SimpleORM {
    private $table, $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, $table) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->table = $table;
    }


    public function findById($id) {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $this->table . ' WHERE ' . $this->primaryKey() . ' = :id');

        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id);
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    }


}
```

So, my question is, how do I write a test for this class?

I can mock PDO, like this:

```
public function testFindById() {
    $pdo = $this->getMock('PDO', array('prepare'));
    $stmt = $this->getMock('PDOStatement', array('execute', 'fetch'));
    $stmt->expects($this->once())->method('execute')->with($this->equalTo(array(':id' => 123)));
    $stmt->expects($this->once())->method('fetch');

    $pdo->expects($this->once())->method('prepare')
                ->with($this->equalTo('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id => :id'))
                ->will($this->returnValue($stmt));


    $mapper = new SimpleOrm($pdo, 'test');
    $mapper->findById(123);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that exposes the internal workings of the `findById()` method to the test, and if they change the test will fail even though the method may have been refactored to work correctly.

In order for the `findById()` method to succeed, it must call `pdo::prepare()` which must return an object that has an `execute()` and `fetch()` method (as the pdostatement does at the moment). However, how can I test this without exposing the implementation of the method to the test?

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the code as is and prefill a database with testable data. That way you need not faux the PDO and you still get the functionality.

Comment: That certainly makes for a less brittle test but it means testing PDO along with the application code, it's not really a unit test because the code being tested isn't isolated. That said, it is definitely a better solution than mocking PDO.